# Why instantiate/destroy are bad in term of performance?

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I heard many about how bad performance Instantiate/destroy gameObjects in game scene dynamically.
So I make object pool for re-use gameObjects.
But I don't understand why the performance is so bad.
Please explain me the reason.

Comment: Check this website, it explain really well. https://www.raywenderlich.com/847-object-pooling-in-unity

Comment: It doesn't answer your question, but if you're having problems with performance in regards to creating/destroying gameobjects, look into creating a pooler. The idea is that objects are created at the start and kept disabled/hidden, and then retrieved from the pool as needed. This gets around the creation/destruction performance hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unity is a hybrid engine, with parts writen in C#, which is a managed language, and parts in C++ which is natvie. An GameObject consists of a part that is visible from the C# side (so you can access it),but also parts that have to be visible to the C++ side which maintains its own list of objects, but also has a list of callbacks that it has to make to the C# code (i.e. Update, OnCollisionEnter etc). With each object you create / instantiate, there's quite lot of shuffling stuff around, allocating/deallocating memory, establishing a list of scripts present on a given object, transforms get updated and generally lots of prep work that the engine requires to run relatively fast afterwards. The onbjects also get scanned via reflection for callbacks, and the process involves a lot of P/Invokes.